# How to find the class of element in a each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a menu system where I can change the style of the active page item in the menu. I am using a separate body class on each page, then I want to cycle through the `li` in the menu and find a match to the body class. At that match I will add the new styling to that menu item.

Here is my code so far.

HTML

```
<body class="home-state">
...

<div class="menu-left">     
  <ul>
    <li class="home-state">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="work-state">
        <a href="/work">Work</a>
    </li>
    <li class="services-state">
        <a href="/services">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="about-state">
        <a href="/about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="blog-state">
        <a href="//blog.example.com" target="_blank">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li class="shop-state">
        <a href="/shop">Shop</a>
    </li>
    <li class="contact-state">
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#modal-coworking">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="project-state">
        <a href="/brief/index">Project brief</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

...
</body>
```

JS

```
var bodyClass = $("body").attr('class');

$('.menu-left ul li').each(function(){
```

**First:** I want to find the element's class here I have used `$(this).attr("class");` which didn't work

```
    var element = $(this);
```

**Second**: I want to use a if statement to check to see if the class matches the bodyClass

```
    console.log(element);
```

**Last**: If there is a match I want to add the class `.active` to the element `li`.

```
});
```

Comment: Is your `<body>` element guaranteed to only have a single class? (I.e., *not* `something like class="home-state big-text"`?)

Comment: I am just manually adding them, however if someone add's a class later on it would break the code. I was thinking of checking the url path and using a regex, however locally I have to add .html to the pages ( something to do with how my vagrant machine ) so If I used the url sniffing option it would work on the live server not the dev and local server. I could do it by ID instead of class since you can only have one ID  for a element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that elements can have multiple classes, I'd suggesting changing your body element to use a `data-` attribute rather than a class to specify what the current page is:

```
<body data-current="home-state">
```

Then the JS needed to add the `active` class to the relevant menu item is simple:

```
$("li." + $("body").attr("data-current")).addClass("active")
```

You don't need to loop over the menu items comparing classes as mentioned in the question, because you can just directly select the required li element based on its class.

In the event that the body element doesn't have a `data-current` attribute then `$("body").attr("data-current")` would return `undefined`, which would mean the code above tries to select an element with `$("li.undefined")` and add a class to it. Probably you have no elements with such a class so that would be harmless, but if you wanted to explicitly test that the `data-current` attribute exists:

```
var current = $("body").attr("data-current")
if (current) {
  $("li." + current).addClass("active")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in couple ways, here is the simple way to do this;

```
var bodyClass = $("body").attr('class');

$("li." + bodyClass).addClass("active")
```

You can also use a loop for this one;

```
var bodyClass = $("body").attr('class');

$(".menu-left li").each(function(i, classes) {
    if (bodyClass === $(this).attr("class")) {
        $(this).addClass("active")
    }
})
```

both will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzj5j.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3k4U.png)

as the comment said,the element can have more than one class ,so you should check it one by one

Comment: if the element with class "menu-left" also have more than one class,you should check it,too.I suggest you to use id rather than class

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You missed to bind the click event for the menu item. Follow like below

```
var bodyClass = $("body").attr('class');
$('.menu-left ul li').on( "click", function() {
var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
   alert(myClass);
});
```

Tested: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XzYjGY

Comment: I don't want to bind a click event. I want to load the page look for the class on the body then match it to the class on the menu so it can have a active class. I want this to happen on page load no clicking would be happening.